# Game Centre cannot be quit in El Capitan 10.11.6

Tags: macos, game-center

[image]

Like this image suggests, the game centre cannot be quit, and there is nothing there. All I can do to quit the game centre is to force quit it. Does anyone know how to solve this? Is this kind of bug or something similar? I did not open the game centre before. This is the first time I open it since I installed el capitan.

Comment: Actually I solved this problem by signing in to the Game Centre via an iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

**Are you logged into your apple account, and is it active with Game Center?** I have had this issue before, and it was because I never signed into Game Center and I quit it too soon. As soon as I clicked cancel when it asks you to long in, I never faced the issue again.